# notepad++ regular expression find and replace getting only last letter of a word instead of entire group

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file where classnames were gives as

```
{styles.classname}
```

I have to change all the occurences like above to below

```
"classname"
```

I tried matching in the following way which matches the occurences

```
\{+[styles]+\.+([\w])+\}
```

The problem is with replace. I used \1 in replace with. But it doesn't replace the whole word but replaces it with only the last letter of the word

```
e
```

Comment: Change `([\w])+` to `([\w]+)`

Comment: Try `\{styles\.(\w+)\}`

Comment: That worked thanks

Comment: Also, I have the feeling you are misunderstanding the regex syntax. You should take a look at some guides, or over regex101.com

Comment: For instance, your regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/skoknR/1) `{{{lye....0123_a564}`

Comment: yeah I don't use regex a lot. So I might have been wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is more than what you inspected. You are using a character class in a wrong context. You don't need `[styles]+` but `styles` alone. You probably don't need all those extra `+` quantifiers and `([\w])+` will result into the last char to be stored in capturing group one. Try:

```
\{styles\.(\w+)\}
```